# Can a player use the Wand of Dowsing card during a combat which is not his?

Tags: munchkin

During a combat I had, a player played a blue card (Wand of Dowsing) and selected a card in the pile that would cancel the combat that I was having. Is that legal ?

The "Wand of Dowsing" card states that:

> Go through the discards to find any one card you want. Take that card and discard this one.

Here is the card:

[image]

Comment: Can you include the text of what the card does?

Comment: Is the card actually Wand of Dowsing?

Comment: I am playing the game in French, so I am not certain of the translation... It is "Baguette de sourcier" in French !

Comment: After some research, @LeppyR64 you were right, it is the Wand of Dowsing ! And Joe  W I added the card's content & image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should help you.

> **Q. The Wand of Dowsing doesn't say "Usable once only," but I have to discard it after I use it. Can I treat it like a one-shot (play it from my hand rather than the table, or play it during combat)?**
> **A.** *The clear intent is that this is a one-shot card, even though it lacks the magical "Usable once only" language, and so the rules of one-shot cards apply to this one as well. It can be played during combat, and it can be used from the hand. We've fixed this error in recent printings.*

Source: [Munchkin FAQ](https://munchkin.game/gameplay/faq/)